# Getting started with Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sqlite

I have a script that currently utilizes the `sqlite3` gem however this has gotten messy so I want to migrate over to Active Record.

I am having trouble getting the basics set up.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(File.open('database.log', 'w'))

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => 'sqlite3',
  :database => 'example.db'
)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'admins'
    create_table :admins do |table|
      table.column :network_id,     :integer
      table.column :text,           :string
    end
  end

  unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'channels'
    create_table :channels do |table|
      table.column :network_id,     :integer
      table.column :channel_name,   :string
      table.column :channel_users,  :integer
      table.column :channel_topic,  :string
    end
  end

  unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'motds'
    create_table :motds do |table|
      table.column :network_id,     :integer
      table.column :text,           :string
    end
  end

  unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'networks'
    create_table :networks do |table|
      table.column :network_id,     :integer
      table.column :network_name,   :string
    end
  end

  unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'servers'
    create_table :servers do |table|
      table.column :network_id,     :integer
      table.column :server_ip,      :string
      table.column :server_port,    :integer
    end
  end

  unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'users'
    create_table :users do |table|
      table.column :network_id,     :integer
      table.column :global,         :integer
      table.column :global_max,     :integer
      table.column :local,          :string
      table.column :local_max,      :integer
    end
  end
end
```

For some reason Active Record is creating more columns that I have set up above and I do not completely understand how to sort it out.

Basically all tables should be linked to the `networks` table, hence why I have set up `network_id` in the other tables, but for some reason Active Record is adding other columns/primary keys like `id`.

Here is `database.log`:

```
D, [2016-01-11T09:36:33.223197 #17400] DEBUG -- :    (3.1ms)  CREATE TABLE "admins" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "network_id" integer, "text" varchar)
D, [2016-01-11T09:36:33.226336 #17400] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  CREATE TABLE "channels" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "network_id" integer, "channel_name" varchar, "channel_users" integer, "channel_topic" varchar)
D, [2016-01-11T09:36:33.229804 #17400] DEBUG -- :    (2.3ms)  CREATE TABLE "motds" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "network_id" integer, "text" varchar)
D, [2016-01-11T09:36:33.232999 #17400] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  CREATE TABLE "networks" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "network_id" integer, "network_name" varchar)
D, [2016-01-11T09:36:33.235667 #17400] DEBUG -- :    (1.4ms)  CREATE TABLE "servers" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "network_id" integer, "server_ip" varchar, "server_port" integer)
D, [2016-01-11T09:36:33.238509 #17400] DEBUG -- :    (1.8ms)  CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "network_id" integer, "global" integer, "global_max" integer, "local" varchar, "local_max" integer)
```

What is the best way to design this in Active Record? The other tables should rely on the `networks` table, for example if something tries to insert in to `channels` with a `network_id` that doesn't exist in `networks` it should error.

Appreciate any assistance with this design to get me on the right track.

Comment: Id is a default primary key, you shouldn't need to add network_id to networks, it's network_id in other tables to point to id column on networks table.

Comment: Have you read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html?

Comment: Active record adds ids by default. It needs them. `network_id` would normally be a foreign key to the id in the `networks` table. If you intend for this to be some sort of external identifier in the `networks` table, then you should rename it to avoid confusion.

Comment: Sorry. So within each table I should remove the `table_` prefix on the columns? For example in the `channels` table remove the `channel_` prefix on the columns and remove the `network_id` column in the `networks` table? Is this how I should design the tables to be used with Active Record? Anyone want to write an answer showing me using my example so I can accept?

Comment: Doesn't ActiveRecord run regardless of which DB you're using???

Comment: @RichPeck Hm, what do you mean? :)

Comment: Well you posted in "Ruby on Rails", so I presumed you were asking about switching from SQLite to ActiveRecord, which is incorrect in the sense of Rails

Comment: I'm asking about switching from native `sqlite3` gem queries to Active Record, not "SQLite" to Active Record. Thanks.